# how secure is passwordcard.org?

Tags: password-management

How secure is passwordcard.org? Assuming user follows recommended precautions:

- Don't read along with your finger, or the smudge will tell a thief where your password is.
- Keep your PasswordCard on your person, don't leave it lying around near your computer.
- Clear your browser cache and history after printing this page.

Comment: What if you memorized a random or semi-random password string as a base for all your passwords, then add a number of digits from the password card to the end of it?
Basically use it as part of a password system, rather than the whole system itself.

Answer (score 19):

I have a quite a few concerns with this service:

1. The premise of the card is flawed.  While it *is* better than simply writing your password down, it's not *much* better.  If the card is known to an attacker there are 8 x 29 starting places and your choice of length and direction of password.  This choice is *very* likely to be 8 and quite likely to be up-right, right, down-right or down (4 possibilities).  An attacker with your card or secret number would likely have your password in 928 attempts.  If you consider lengths longer than 8 and directions that go left, multiply that number by the number of possible lengths and/or directions. 8 rows x 29 columns x 8 possible lengths x 8 possible directions still only gives 14848.  The card provides very little extra protection than simply writing your password down.
2. Your card is defined by a *secret number*.  If anyone knows this secret number, they can regenerate the entire card by visiting the site and typing in that number.  This number leaks all over the place on the site in question.

   - The site does not default to using SSL, even though the site is available using an SSL connection.  Below the card there is a list of options and one of those is "Secure connection".  Next to this is a tiny arrow.  That arrow is a link to the SSL version of the site.  Your secret number will be visible in network traffic if you are not using SSL.  There is also a link to the SSL version in the FAQ.
   - The image is pulled in to the page with a URL that includes the secret number.
   - Some pages ([such as this one](http://www.passwordcard.org/en/panel?number=4cdf1e93c5229716)) cause the image to be linked from `http://www.passwordcard.org/generatecard.do?number=4cdf1e93c5229716&cookie=-n0uofpzgp7x7&allowCaching=true` which causes the image to be sent back with an `Expires:` header that allows it to be cached for a year.  Although they have a precaution to "Clear your browser cache and history after printing this page." this does nothing to prevent intermediate third parties such as your ISP from caching.  This is in contradiction to the FAQ which states that only images on the mobile site are cacheable.
   - The secret number is put in a cookie: `number:ce9916b2fb16f213` with a *very* long expiry date.

     ```
     Set-Cookie: number=ce9916b2fb16f213; Domain=.passwordcard.org; Expires=Thu, 08-May-2081 13:00:58 GMT; Path=/
     ```
   - Both the cached image and the cookie end up on your hard drive, meaning that even if you delete them, they can be recovered unless you use a secure delete process.
   - The site pulls in javascript from several other sources including `addthis.com`, `facebook.net`, `google-analytics.com` and `google.com`.  The FAQ is mostly but not completely consistent with what I see on the site.  Note that the domains may also differ, such as `m.addthisedge.com` and `ssl.gstatic.com`
   - On [this page](http://www.passwordcard.org/en/panel?number=1cc09968cc0f6c31), the Google Analytics javascript in particular caused this request to be sent:

     > **http://www.google-analytics.com**/_*utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.1&utms=30&utmn=482475756&utmhn=www.passwordcard.org&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1080&utmvp=700x626&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=0&utmfl=11.6%20r602&utmdt=Your%20PasswordCard&utmhid=257017121&utmr=0&utmp=%2Fen%2Fpanel%3F
     >   **number%3D1cc09968cc0f6c31**&utmht=1366451569430&utmac=UA-9164771-1&utmcc=*_utma%3D18293158.224629233.1366447288.1366447288.1366447288.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D18293158.1366447288.1.1.utmcsr%3Dsecurity.stackexchange.com%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fquestions%2F34602%2Fhow-secure-is-passwordcard-org%3B&utmu=DB~
   - The secret number is written on the card itself.  It is *much* easier to shoulder-surf just that number than the entire card.
3. The code that generates the secret numbers is available on the site and does use `java.security.SecureRandom`, which is good.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Java to know whether `nextLong()` automatically seeds the PRNG the same way that `nextBytes()` does.  If the seed for the CSPRNG is predictable, the secret numbers become predictable.
4. To generate the strings that are used for the passwords, `java.util.Random` is used with the secret number as the seed.  The PRNG used for `java.util.Random` has [serious](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/lcg_planes.shtml) [problems](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/lcg_bit_positions.shtml) for *anything* related to security.  So much so that [non-security-related games developers notice them by accident](http://www.ziggysgames.com/noticed-something-interesting-about-the-java-random-number-generator).  The specific problem with this code is that it may introduce patterns in the passwords that would make them more predictable without even knowing the secret key.

In the end, your usage of PasswordCard should be dictated by your risk tolerance.  All the above possibilities are unlikely to happen to a random person.  If you were the CEO or Sysadmin for a company with some significant value in an industry on China's five year strategic plan, the likelihood of there being an attacker actively trying to get your information is somewhat higher than if we're talking about a high-schooler's Reddit account.

You can mitigate most of the above leakage problems by [downloading the Java source code](http://www.passwordcard.org/algorithm.html) and generating your password card on your own machine.

You can be certain of the seeding by modifying the code to [call `nextBytes()` directly after instantiating the SecureRandom object](https://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/).

You can mitigate the predictable strings problem by modifying the code to use a second instance of `java.security.SecureRandom` for the password strings rather than `java.util.Random`.

Comment: `nextLong()` is implemented by calling `next(32)` twice (to get two random 32-bit integers). `SecureRandom` has its own `next()` implementation which uses `nextBytes()`. `nextBytes()` does automatic seeding from what the underlying OS provides (e.g. `/dev/urandom`) so that one, at least, is safe.

Comment: Also Chrome reports that the site uses weak security configuration (SHA-1 signatures), so the connection may not be private.

Comment: Brilliant! Honestly after reading your analysis, I feel that you could invent a much more secure alternative based on the same concept. But the cream of the crop is this: _"In the end, your usage of PasswordCard should be dictated by your risk tolerance."_ PS: I learnt what "shoulder surfing" means :)

Comment: PS: Given that the author of the site has updated it to address some of the problems, would you update your answer (strike out rather than delete what's obsolete) and possibly do another round of analysis, please?

Comment: The site seems to default to SSL now.

Answer (score 14):

Answering the question instead of commenting on Ladadadada's answer as I don't seem to have enough reputation to comment directly (even though I do on stackoverflow; isn't that shared?). Apologies if this is a breach of etiquette!

I'm the author of passwordcard.org. Thanks, Ladadadada, for your thorough analysis! It's the most thorough I've seen so far. Your points are valid, and I agree with your conclusions. The password card is by no means meant to be iron clad secure, it's only meant to be *more* secure than the current practice of many people.

I'll address some of the points you mention, such as bringing the FAQ up to date, and reducing unnecessary enabling of caching and setting of cookies. Just to explain one point specifically: the reason the site doesn't default to SSL is that Google Adsense does not work over SSL, and I need the ad revenue to pay for the hosting costs. Not the best of reasons, I admit.

If anyone has questions about me or passwordcard.org, let me know. (Probably not here though. What's the accepted way to ask specific questions of someone publicly?)

Comment: You handle criticism well.  That's a very reassuring trait in a developer.  I look forward to seeing the improvements.

Comment: +1 for accepting constructive criticism, unlike [certain other people](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/250/ciphercloud-dmca-notice).

Comment: @Pepijn two options for asking questions - either you could pop into our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) if you wanted to discuss here (you need 20 rep, which you now have) or you could supply a contact form/suggestion box or the like. We're all friendly in chat :)

Comment: You could at least upgrade the SSL certificate to one that uses SHA-256. dabest1 pointed this out in January and the certificate is *still* SHA-1. Using SHA-1 is perhaps not an *immediate* concern, but it's a completely unnecessary weakness IMO.

Comment: Well it took a year or four ;), but at least now the site is https-only, and uses SHA256.

Answer (score 6):

It's as secure as any other password written down, except these passwords they generate are quite strong.

**IF** you follow their best practices, you'll be okay...but that is a big **IF**. You're bound to leave it around. You're bound to get sloppy.

Once you get sloppy, and someone finds it....it is trivial to try all of the passwords on the sheet....

edit : Honestly. I don't see why people don't just memorize a few passwords. How many dang phone numbers did you used to remember before your cell-phone knew all of them? I bet a lot. Use that extra brain-drive space to hold a few passwords.

Comment: +1, it really isn't *that* difficult to remember a handful of passwords and some logical variations. In all fairness though, if most systems had the same password requirements it would be easier use the same complex password for each system, which could be a downfall. Maybe that's a good reason why certain systems only allow *certain* special chars, drives me nuts.

Comment: if you're perception is that 'you're bound to get sloppy' then wouldn't that imply that any password management system is worthless ? for example even memorizing doesn't prevent keyloggers, which could be introduced by carelessness.

Comment: I think it's a little more secure than a password simply written down, since you're memorizing a pattern and an index by which to look up passwords in a seemingly random piece of text. Sure, brute forcing could eventually give both the pattern and the password to a hacker using the card stolen from you, but it's still slower than simply using a written obviously demarcated password stolen from you. (Yes, it's only a bit more secure by a tiny margin, given Ladadadada's brilliant analysis, but the point is, it's not "as secure as".)